# How can I enlarge text by a multiplier using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, font-size

I have been creating a javascript function which enlarges text according to a multiplier. The multiplier is used as I eventually hope to create a 'user enters text size' system. I have developed some code which I think will work. (The multiplier is declared within the button). It isn't much, and perhaps I have been doing this entirely the wrong way, but here's the code.

```js
function enlarge(size) {
  var result = str.fontsize(size);
  document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize = result;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="enlarge(50)">Click me to alter text size</button>

<div id="demo">
  HELLO WORLD
</div>
```

Comment: Did you have a question about it? Otherwise, this kind of post would be better on code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: str is not defined"`

Comment: Sorry, @JacobPenny, I wasn't aware of code review at the time of writing. Thanks for clarifying what it is!